# RichTextBlock is losing 'hr' feature

Tags: wagtail

The wagtail CMS editor's RichTextBlock does not display the horizontal line option even I put 'hr' in the features list.

My feature's list is `['h1,'hr','h2']` as I code it like

```
paragraph_block = RichTextBlock(features=['h1','hr','h2'])
```

[image]

Is horizontal line being removed from the features list of RichTextBlock?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the UI changes that works once you know the trick but is a bit hidden. On the line where you want the horizontal rule, type three dashes `---`. When you type the third one the -- will turn into a horizontal rule.